# Dropdown ul li with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My purpose is: when using method 'click', li will be appear with method fadeToggle in jQuery.

Here is my code. The problem here is when click any ULs, all LIs of all other uls also appear.

```js
 $('ul').on('click', function(){
      $('li').fadeToggle("fast");
});
```

```css
a{
  text-decoration:none;
  padding: 20px;
}
ul{
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:green;
  padding:10px;
  color:white;
  margin: 10px;
}
li{
  background-color:pink;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>HOME
 <li><a href="#" title="">AAAAAA</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" title="">BBBBBB</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" title="">AAAAAA</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" title="">AAAAAA</a></li>
</ul>

<ul>CONTACT
 <li><a href="#" title="">AAAAAA</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" title="">BBBBBB</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" title="">AAAAAA</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" title="">AAAAAA</a></li>
</ul>

<ul>BYE
 <li><a href="#" title="">AAAAAA</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" title="">BBBBBB</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" title="">AAAAAA</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" title="">AAAAAA</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the current `ul` with `$(this)`, then find 'li's inside of that `ul` and toggle them.

```js
 $('ul').on('click', function(){
      $(this).find('li').fadeToggle("fast");
});
```

```css
a{
  text-decoration:none;
  padding: 20px;
}
ul{
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:green;
  padding:10px;
  color:white;
  margin: 10px;
}
li{
  background-color:pink;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>HOME
 <li><a href="#" title="">AAAAAA</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" title="">BBBBBB</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" title="">AAAAAA</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" title="">AAAAAA</a></li>
</ul>

<ul>CONTACT
 <li><a href="#" title="">AAAAAA</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" title="">BBBBBB</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" title="">AAAAAA</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" title="">AAAAAA</a></li>
</ul>

<ul>BYE
 <li><a href="#" title="">AAAAAA</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" title="">BBBBBB</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" title="">AAAAAA</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" title="">AAAAAA</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I got it. Thanks so much.